# python pandas removing brackets and , in df values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as below:

```
column1    column2     column3    column4
6,546      543,254,32  (443,326)  (32,000)
4,554      432,885     (88,974)    77,332
n.a        -           5,332       -
...        ...        ...         ...

# this df stretches for over 500 rows, and all columns could potentially have 
# values within brackets, 'n.a', '-'
```

What I am having trouble with, is replacing all the values in `( , )` to be `-443326` *ie, removing the brackets and the commas*

I understand that I can do `df.replace('n.a', numpy.nan, inplace=True)` and this will replace the values accordingly if they match.

However, the same for `df.replace('(', numpy.nan, inplace=True)` does not work.

I have tried using a loop to solve my issue:

```
for i in df.columns():
    df[i] = df[i].str.replace('(', '-')
    df[i] = df[i].str.replace(')', '')
    df[i] = df[i].str.replace(',', '')
```

This seems to work, but it gives me a warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How

Comment: @jezrael I think `str` is required in `df[i].str.replace('\(', '-')`

Comment: @tarashypka - it depends if need [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I think I must have missed your answer in my previous post. Apologies for duplicating the same question. I've tried the solutions you have provided and it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different approach:

```
In [89]: df.replace(r'[^\d\.]+', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
Out[89]:
   column1     column2  column3  column4
0   6546.0  54325432.0   443326  32000.0
1   4554.0    432885.0    88974  77332.0
2      NaN         NaN     5332      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {
    ',': '',
    '\(([\d,]+)\)': r'-\1',
    'n.a': 'nan',
    '^-$': 'nan',
}

df.replace(d, regex=True).astype(float)

   column1     column2   column3  column4
0   6546.0  54325432.0 -443326.0 -32000.0
1   4554.0    432885.0  -88974.0  77332.0
2      NaN         NaN    5332.0      NaN
```

---

If you just want to solve the `(stuff)` problem

```
d = {
    '\(([\d,]+)\)': r'-\1',
}

df.replace(d, regex=True)

  column1     column2   column3  column4
0   6,546  543,254,32  -443,326  -32,000
1   4,554     432,885   -88,974   77,332
2     n.a           -     5,332        -
```

Answer (score 0):

chained replace.

```
df['column_name'] = (df.loc[:, 'column_name'].replace('[)]', '', regex=True)
                            .replace('[(]', '-', regex=True).astype(float))
```